# How to select a radio button where its tag is hidden

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I'm learning python and trying to do a basic click on a radio button. At the moment the 'return' radio button is selected and instead I want the 'one-way' radio button to be selected. However, when I run my code, it states it cannot find the 'one-way' radio button.

I want to ask what do I need to do to be able to find a radio but that's hidden under various other tags?

Below is the basic code:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'option')]")
one_way = element.find_element_by_id('one-way').click()
```

Updated code (still not working):

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
    from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get("https://xxxxx/xxx/")

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    actions = ActionChains(driver)

    # wait for the page to load
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "search-form-content")))

    # fill out the form

    element = driver.find_element_by_id('one-way')
    driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', element)
    element.click()

   # previously just tried driver.find_element_by_id('one-way').click() and    #one_way = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class_name='carat']/div[@class_name='option']/input[@id='one-way']").click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Interacting with invisible / hidden elements is not supported by Selenium per default.** You may fetch all texts/values of the options, but cannot interact with them.

There is a *good* reason why this element or option is hidden: the user may not choose it. For example an option shall only be available for premium users. In this case a good web-server, which does validation checks, will raise an error.

Another remark:

In general you can use the idea of a **Select-Element** like explained on the official Selenium documentation (for visible elements):

```
select = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("select")
allOptions = select.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")
for option in allOptions:
    print "Value is: " + option.get_attribute("value")
    option.click()
```

http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

Comment: Since you mentioned premium users, it sounds like a very legitimate testcase to ensure that you *do* validate this on the server side even if the client tampers with a hidden option.

Answer (score 0):

Since an element `id` is unique, you don't actually require the first line of your code. Use:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('one-way')
```

This will select the desired element. However, if the element isn't in view (ie not visible within the browser), you may need to scroll to the element before clicking it. To do this, use:

```
driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', element)
```

This will scroll the element into view. You can then click it using:

```
element.click()
```

Comment: That's what I tried first time but it stated this as an error: 'ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with'

Comment: That doesn't seem to work as well. I'll give you the url of the web so you can see what I'm trying to do. https://reservations.jet2.com/mobile/. When page opens, just want to click on the 'One Way' button. I put my full current code (including your example' in the question

Comment: current error when trying your code: WebDriverException: Message: this.getChromeWindowFromDocumentWindow(...) is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Use JAVASCRIPT/jQuery click..
It'll work even if your element is not visible..

driver.executeScript("$x('your xpath')[0].click());